# visual undeclared identifiers?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i'm using visual studio 2010 and when i do something like

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
        if(m_Var == 1)
            j++;
}

if(j == 0)//This line errors undeclared identifier
    DoSomething();
```

I have declared `j` in the for loop so why is it erroring "undeclared identifier"?

another example would be

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
        m_Var1++;
}

for(i = 0; i < 200; i++)//This line errors undeclared identifier
{
        m_Var2++;
}
```

that code errors even though it is declared in the for loop, but why? is there a way to do this without having to declare `i` BEFORE the loop but declare it within the loop instead like in the above examples?

Comment: For your second example, defining `i` in both loops is better style anyway.

Answer (score 5):

In the first example, `j` only exists in the scope of the loop

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
        if(m_Var == 1) j++;
}  // i, j exist no longer
```

In the second example, the same applies to `i`. It's scope is the first loop. You can even check it without a loop:

```
{
  int i = 0;
} // end of scope, end of i

i++; // error,
```

Answer (score 4):

As I recall, some very early versions of C++ had variables defined in `for` loops scoped to the block containing the loop.  In modern C++, the scope is restricted to the `for` loop itself.  For example:

```
void foo() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++) {
        // i is visible here
    }
    // In very old C++, i is visible here.
    // In modern C++, i is not visible here.
}
```

Visual Studio actually has an option to enable the old behavior; you can turn off "Force Conformance in For Loop Scope", under Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> Language. The corresponding compiler command-line option is `/Zc:forScope-`.  But unless you specifically need this to compile old code that you can't afford to fix, I strongly recommend leaving it with the default setting, which conforms to the modern C++ rule.  If you're writing new code, just follow the modern C++ rule.  If you need a variable to be visible outside the loop, then declare it outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Because you declare it in the loop so once the loop has finished, your `j` variable is out of scope. When you declare variables inside the for statement like this

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

the variable only has loop scope.

Answer (score 1):

> I have declared `j` in the `for` loop ...

Yes, you have. And you can only *use* it in that `for` loop, because its scope ends at the closing brace of that loop. You cannot use it after that.

If you want to use it afterwards, you must move the scope out a little bit, but not so far that it will affect other stuff (localisation is still a good thing). One method is to use block scope, something like:

```
{
    int i, j;                          // Scope starts here,
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (m_Var == 1)
            j++;
    if (j == 0)                        // still exists here,
        DoSomething();
}                                      // and ends here.
```

This still limits `i` and `j` to a specific, small area, but allows `j` to "escape" from the `if` statement.

Comment: It's the scope of `j`, not its storage duration, that's relevant.

Comment: Good point, Keith, even now, after three-plus decades of C coding, I sometimes get confused. Changed to fix.

Answer (score 0):

c++ uses block scope for that variable - [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b80153d8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)